# Error in invoking target 'libasmclntsh19.ohso libasmperl19.ohso client_sharedlib' of makefile 'ins_rdbms.mk'

Tags: oracle

I am getting below error while installing oracle database 19c on RHEl 9.3 machine . Any solution to fix the error.

Error in invoking target 'libasmclntsh19.ohso libasmperl19.ohso client_sharedlib' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'.
See '/tmp/InstallActions2023-12-07_02-10-24PM/installActions2023-12-07_02-10-24PM.log' for details.

i am looking for solution .

Comment: "See '/tmp/InstallActions2023-12-07_02-10-24PM/installActions2023-12-07_02-10-24PM.log' for details." Did you look for details there?

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to install on OL9?

And if you look in the log file you will see:
INFO: 
/usr/bin/ld
INFO: 
: cannot find 
INFO: 
/usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a
INFO:

Answer (score 2):

On Linux: The files crti.o and libpthread_nonshared.a missing and it is due to glibc-devel rpm.

Check glibc-devel
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/crti.o
glibc-devel-2.17-157.el7.x86_64
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a
glibc-devel-2.17-157.el7.x86_64

Install glibc-devel rpm and then re-try the 19c installation.

You can install the glibc-devel by yum :

yum install glibc-devel

If the problem still exists, probably it is a bug 33794281.

You can resolves this by installing patch 35775632.

Download the patch from https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/SimpleSearch/process_form?search_type=patch&patch_number=35775632&plat_lang=226P&display_type=&search_style=8&orderby=&direction=&old_type_list=&gobuttonpressed=&sortcolpressed=&tab_number=&c_release_parent=product&c_product_child=release

File name is p35775632_190000_Linux-x86-64.zip

And install it following instructions in README file:

- Download stubs.tar from Patch 35775632 and extract
- Copy stubs.tar into $ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs and extract (cmd: $ tar -xf stubs.tar)

Try it should work